# Php Calender Week Range

Tags: php, date, random, range

I want to concate a php range so to say,
 code looks like this so far:

```
$var1 = $date->format('W');

if($var2 > 52) {

    $var2 = $var2 % 52;

}

    $numbers = range($var1,$var2);

    shuffle($numbers);

    foreach($users as $user) {

        $uniqueRand = array_pop($numbers);
        ...
    }
```

So I want to give the users at my database a random number / calenderweek,
which is between the current calender week and a the current calender week +15.

I am checking if the calender week of var2 is higher than 52, if it is higher then the calender week starts from 1, in my case the calender weeks are from 43 - 6.

The problem is now that the range goes from 43 to 6, but I want that the range does from 43 to 52 and than from 1 to 6 , does anyone have a good solution for this issue.

Comment: i think you should initialize that to 1 instead of taking mod for value.

Comment: Out of interest: The question seems to be rather similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212325/php-random-fill-range). Is there some kind of connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You think too complicated. Let your random range run just in a plain sequence (in this case, from 0 to 14), and do the modulus afterwards:

```
$var1 = $date->format('W');
$numbers = range(0,14);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach($users as $user) {
    $uniqueRand = (array_pop($numbers)+$var1) % 52 + 1;
    ...
}
```

Comment: NICE! WORKED!!
May you explain that solution

Comment: @slark Edited my answer. Hope it's sufficient.